# Static Analyzer to find no. of times functions are called in java

Tags: java, android, static-analysis

I have a very big list of java files. I need a tool which will give me number of times a function is used for all the functions from all the sour code files. Is there any such tool exist? I need this information to optimize those functions that are used more number of times.

Comment: ok with downvote. But why?

Comment: Yes, such things exist. I use [Google's Error Prone](http://errorprone.info) at work, but others are available. However, when you say "optimize", what are you really asking? If you mean to find and remove bottlenecks, static analysis isn't the right tool, because a slow method called once might be worse than a fast method called 100 times. You need to use a profiler instead

Comment: Thanks Andy. I agree. But I have a special requirement to find so. Will try Google's Error Prone.